# Add LogEntry to endpoint and retrieve changes in django rest for each user activity

Tags: logging, django-rest-framework

I am trying to add user activity log using the django built in model `LogEntry`.

In this application I am using `simpleJWT` to authenticate using token.

However the changes are not appearing on the api when you are logged using the token authentication. I've seen that only when I am logged in `admin` that I can see the changes, both in the admin and the `LogEntry` endpoint.

```
# serializers.py ----

class LogEntrySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = LogEntry
        fields = '__all__'

# viewsets.py ----

class LogEntryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = LogEntry.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LogEntrySerializer
```

I know that there are packages such as `django-simple-history` that may help me with this issue. However I want to pass all of the user activity logs into the `LogEntry` model but I have no clue how to do this approach without adding a query into each method for each endpoint.